# Stripe Card Element using React with Django Backend

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I try to implement Stripe Card Element with React using the following code :

```
const CreditModalCard = ({ ModalPlanData, ModalStatus, SetModalStatus }) => {
    const [ModalplanMonthly, setModalplanMonthly] = useState(false);
    const planModalClose = () => SetModalStatus(false);
    const ModalPlanchange = val => { if (!isSubmit) setModalplanMonthly(val); }

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    const creditForm = useRef();
    const [ErrMsg, SetErrMsg] = useState("");
    const [isSubmit, SetisSubmit] = useState(false);
    const [SuccessSub, SetSuccessSub] = useState(false);

return (
    label className={`${isSubmit ? 'subscription-disable' : ''}`}>Payment Option</label>
    <Box className="planModal-rightBody-cardElementWrapper">
    <Box className="planModal-rightBody-cardElement">
    <CardElement options={{ hidePostalCode: true, disabled: isSubmit }} />
    </Box>
    </Box>
)
```

However when I try to use the same card element in backend with the following code :

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(customer_resultState.data.clientsecret, {
  payment_method: {
    card: info.card_element,
    billing_details: {
      name: "Name Surname",
    },
  }
}).then((result) => { ...
})
```

I get the following error :

```
Received unknown parameters: livemode, type, created, id, object, card
```

The info struct is coming from the stripe.createPaymentMethod function :

```
const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({ type: "card", card: elements.getElement(CardElement) });
        if (error || !paymentMethod) {
            SetisSubmit(false);
            SetErrMsg(error.message);
            return;
        }

        let creditInfo = {
            product : GetSelectedPlan(),
            email: checkemail,
            card: paymentMethod,
            plan: ModalplanMonthly ? "monthly" : "annualy"
        };
```

Here below are the output that I got for payment_method_id and client secret, while the last error is the message that I get from "stripe.confirmCardPayment" function :

```
payment_method_id : pm_1MgevyLS6SANVcyC5hbsq1n3

clientsecret : pi_3MgebQLS6SANVcyC1mBTVxTu_secret_xDLFXOqlpIU9tF8wuwaos8uxN
shared-b4b210b16164b8ff74109e131a66ac59.js:1          

POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_3MgebQLS6SANVcyC1mBTVxTu/confirm 400

A processing error occurred.
```

What should I do to correctly send the card data into confirmCardPayment function as an argument ?

Comment: you need to create a `PaymentIntent` using the client secret and `PaymentMethod` ID, after that you need to confirm the `PaymentIntent` instead of confirming the `PaymentMethod`directly.

Comment: I am using subscription backend flow, so the client secret is implicitly created when the subscription (and an associated payment intend) is created for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first piece of advice would be to not nest these values inside objects so you don't pass more data than you expect.

The signature for the [confirmCardPayment](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) function expects the Payment Intent `client_secret` as the first argument and then an `data` object.  The first element there is either an object including `cardElement` (if you are collecting card info during the confirmation) or the ID for the Payment Method if you are using an existing one.

Based on the error message you are receiving the `/confirm` endpoint is getting some extra parameters it does not expect so I would start by assigning the values you need to their own `const`'s and logging them to your console to make sure you are passing what is expected.

Comment: Now I have changed the code into "stripe.confirmCardPayment(customer_resultState.data.clientsecret, {
          payment_method: info.payment_method_id,
        }).then((result) => {", Stripe-js now makes an implicit API call to https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_XXX/confirm but fails with 400 and with a popup of "A processing error occurred." message.

Comment: What shall I exactly do here to check the extra parameters in your comment "Based on the error message you are receiving the /confirm endpoint is getting some extra parameters it does not expect so I would start by assigning the values you need to their own const's and logging them to your console to make sure you are passing what is expected." ? Which parameters should I log and check ?

Comment: Where is the documentation for the /confirm endpoint ? I am not making any explicit call to paymentintent confirm endpoint, which function is doing this implicitly ?

Comment: Assign the Payment Method ID and client secret to their own variables and log them to your console.  
The documentation for the Payment Intent confirmation API is here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm

But you should focus on the confirmCardPayment function doc I linked.

Comment: These below are what you have requested in terms of payment method id and client secret : 

payment_method_id : pm_1MgevyLS6SANVcyC5hbsq1n3
clientsecret : pi_3MgebQLS6SANVcyC1mBTVxTu_secret_xDLFXOqlpIU9tF8wuwaos8uxN
shared-b4b210b16164b8ff74109e131a66ac59        POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_3MgebQLS6SANVcyC1mBTVxTu/confirm 400, 
ApiProvider.js:262 A processing error occurred.